# How to safe a column from diagonal element to the bottom

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to get the L and U--matrices from the following Gauss-elimination code I wrote

```
matrix = np.array ([[2,1,4,1], [3,4,-1,-1] , [1,-4,1,5] , [2,-2,1,3]], dtype = float)
vector = np.array([-4, 3, 9, 7], float)
length = len(vector)
L_matrix = np.zeros((4,4), float)
U_matrix = np.zeros((4,4), float)

for m in range(length):
    L_matrix[:,m] = matrix[:,m]
    div = matrix[m,m]
    matrix[m,:] /= div
    U_matrix[m, :] = matrix[m,:]
    vector[m] /= div
```

I'm getting the right U-matrix, but I'm getting this L-matrix

```
[[  2.    0.5   2.    0.5]
 [  3.    2.5  -2.8  -1. ]
 [  1.   -4.5 -13.6  -0. ]
 [  2.   -3.  -11.4  -1. ]]
```

i.e I'm getting the whole matrix instead of a lower triangular matrix with zeros at the top! What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the provided code does not perform the elimination. Try this:

```py
for m in range(length):
    div = matrix[m, m]
    L_matrix[:, m] = matrix[:, m] / div
    U_matrix[m, :] = matrix[m, :]
    matrix -= np.outer(L_matrix[:, m], U_matrix[m, :])
```

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Through_recursion) for more details. For actually solving your linear system, the issue is that LU is not exactly the same as standard Gaussian elimination. You can use [back substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution) to efficiently compute what `vector` should be.